# sublime text 2 list of xml tags for themes

Tags: sublimetext2, text-editor

Where can I find a list of all available xml tags to build a color theme?

ie.

```
<key>findHighlight</key>
<string>#FFE792</string>
```

where is a list for all of the tags such as findHighlight, findHighlightForeground, etc ...

I can't find it on the sublime site.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The best way to learn how to construct themes is to take apart existing ones - that's how I learned. I have yet to find a comprehensive resource on theming in Sublime Text and TextMate (which heavily influenced Jon Skinner, the author of ST). There are bits here and there with a few scopes, or a couple tips, so if someone else has found (or written) something I'd love to hear about it too.

And, a bit of blatant self-promotion - if you'd like a large collection of scopes from which to start designing your own, check out my [Neon Color Scheme](https://github.com/MattDMo/Neon-color-scheme), also available via [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Neon%20Color%20Scheme). It's goal is to make as many languages as possible look as good as possible, and to that end I've assembled as many unique scopes as I can get my hands on. Feel free to fork it on GitHub and play around with it; if you end up releasing something for the world to see just drop me a line so I can check it out!

Another tool I'd highly recommend is facelessuser's [ScopeHunter](https://github.com/facelessuser/ScopeHunter) plugin. It has a lot more functionality than the built-in scope-viewing options, and is invaluable if you're doing theming.

Finally, check out [Color Highlighter](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Color%20Highlighter) and [ColorPicker](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/ColorPicker) - the first highlights hex color codes (among other formats) in your file with that color, allowing you to see what you're working with, and the second pulls up your OS's color picker widget so you can choose a new one if you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I have been looking at the other themes, but you are right there isn't, or at least I can't find, a comprehensive list of xml tags for themes. Your themes look very nice. Do you by any chance know how to change the color when multi select shows all similar words in a file?

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean - do you mean selecting all instances of a certain color and replacing them to something else?

Comment: Oh, never mind, I know what you're talking about - the highlight color of the box around the same word, right?